# SQL Conditional sum and grouping

Tags: sql, grouping, sybase, conditional-statements

I have a query that's trying to sum up a patient's length of stay at a hospital. Here is an example of the data

```
| Patient | Admission_ID | Admission_Event_ID | Admission_Event_Type  | Start Date | End Date   | Duration | Linked_Admission |
| P0001   | ADM0001      | AE1                | (formal) Separation   | 2012-12-18 | 2012-12-18 | 0        | ADM0002          |
| P0001   | ADM0001      | AE2                | Statistical Admission | 2012-12-17 | 2012-12-18 | 1        | ADM0002          |
| P0001   | ADM0002      | AE3                | Statistical Separation| 2012-12-17 | 2012-12-17 | 0        | NULL             |
| P0001   | ADM0002      | AE4                | (formal) Admission    | 2012-11-30 | 2012-12-17 | 17       | NULL             |
| P0002   | ADM0003      | AE5                | (formal) Admission    | 2012-11-30 | 2012-12-25 | 25       | NULL             |
. . .
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, there is a column that links the admission ID (only used when the patient is statistically separated and admitted)

---

By definition, the length of stay is calculated for each patient from the start of their admission until they are separation (statistical separations and admission carry on with the admission, but they're given a new **Admission ID**

A report is run to find out the average length of stay (ALOS) for the hospital and it's unit, the user selects two dates to report between. I've used a CTE (lets call it **CTESep**) to get all the patient's that have been **formally separated** between the reporting period. I then use another CTE (called **CTEAdmissions**) to get all the admissions of the patients within CTESep. This is where I get stuck.

I need to sum up the Durations of the patient to get their total length of stay for that admission (which is a combination of ADM0001 and ADM0002) so the total LOS will be 18, rather than 17 and 1.
My idea was to

```
    ORDER BY Patient
    , End_Date DESC
    , adm_id
    , CASE WHEN 
            Admission_Event_Type  = '(formal) Separation   ' THEN 1
           WHEN Admission_Event_Type  = 'Statistical Admission ' THEN 2
           WHEN Admission_Event_Type  = 'Statistical Separation' THEN 3
           WHEN Admission_Event_Type  = '(formal) Admission    ' THEN 4 
      END ASC
```

Then sum up the duration on based on a condition. The condition rule is *'Start summing up the duration of each patient's admission from a formal separation to a formal admission'*. Which I'm not sure how to do.
I've tried:

```
SELECT SUM(Duration) OVER(PARTITION BY Patient) AS 'Sum'
```

But that will give me the total LOS for the patient across ALL their admissions (if they have more than one separation within that reporting period)
I've also tried

```
 SELECT SUM(Duration) OVER(PARTITION BY Patient, Admission_ID) AS 'Sum'
```

But of course that gives me the LOS of a patient between a formal admission and a statistical separation (and not the LOS by its actual definition).

Anyone got a different way of tackling this problem? By the way, using Sybase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
select patientid,
       admissionid,
       datediff(day, 
                  max(case when Admission_Event_Type = '(formal) Separation   ' then startdate end),
                  max(case when Admission_Event_Type = '(formal) Admission    ' then enddate end)
               ) as total_length
from data
group by patientid, admissionid
```

Comment: That might work, but what if that patient was admitted and separated multiple times (formally) within the reporting period (say over a year or two)

Comment: well since we're grouping by admissionid, these will be returned as separate rows, if you want the total be each patient, you could enlcose in another group by patient.

Comment: That will still return separate rows as the admission ids have different values. I've edited my question to include a column which I thought might help. Links a statistical admission to a statistical separation.

Comment: I don't understand. you want the average length of stay across all patients right? so if i've been to the hospital twice, 10 days the first time 20 days the second time, and you've been to the hospital once for 30 days, the answer will be 20?

Comment: The real world situation is a bit more complex, the query will get the ALOS across a set of multiple different realms (ALOS spent within a particular ward, across the hospital, across the campus). So I need to find the length of stay for each patients admission (formal beginning to end) individually. Once I get the total duration of the admission, I will be able to report the correct ALOS across all realms. Its taken me months to understand the data, so I can see why it might seem confusing

Comment: That's what I though, won't my query give you this?

Comment: Not without linking the admissionsid together somehow with the linked_adm_id. There can be multiple statistical separations and admissions within a formal admission.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79717/discussion-between-maxymoo-and-rook).